# "Mock compiler : Source not found" Error in Remix online IDE

Tags: solidity, remix, compiler

I haven't been able to compile any solidity code because of this error.
How do I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23414)

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The 'version' in the web address is wrong.  Try just http://remix.ethereum.org or put it in directly...like this:

http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.19+commit.c4cbbb05.js

Comment: Yes I did try the link you provided but it still loaded with; http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=builtin. Do I need to install anything on my computer (like downloading and running an ethereum testnet) before I use the Remix IDE browser????  OR does the IDE work on specific browsers only??

Comment: I have the same issue every time I try to reach remix.ethereum.org, whether I get on the google indexed link, type the link by hand or click on any link that does not explicitly specify the version, I get redirected to http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&version=builtin.
Worse - Once I've reached this link once, whatever the version I try to input will always redirect me to the 'builtin' version and fail to compile. 
Why?

Comment: Having the same problem, did someone solve it?

Answer (score 0):

My dirty workaround:

1. install remix locally `npm install remix-ide -g`
2. clone [solc-bin](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-bin) to `remix-ide` package folder (you may find it by `which remix-ide`)
3. change `baseurl: 'https://solc-bin.ethereum.org/bin'` to `baseurl: 'solc-bin/bin'` at `build/app.js`

Comment: I looks like the old Github IO *Browser Solidity* is still working so you can use this one if you don't want to install `node` : http://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/

Answer (score 0):

As with Url `version=builtin` in [Remix-ID](http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=true&version=builtin) is having problem .

**Solution:**

Use old version for right now it's working fine 
[Remix-Id Old Version](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#optimize=false&version=soljson-v0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.js)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was very simple.

1. Delete all of the Cache and Cookies.
2. Load the IDE URL without any parameter : https://remix.ethereum.org
3. It will take a bit time to compile and after finishing you can change the files or codes.